# Setting Font-Family (Django + Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

Currently have the following CSS stylesheet which should apply Courier New to a, p, h1, h2, etc...

```
a, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: "Courier New";
  color: #54627B;
}
```

My a tags are showing as Courier New.
However, the Font-Family for my h1 are not. They are showing up as:

```
-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji"
```

It looks like Bootstrap is overriding the Font Family (even though it should not; my custom stylesheet is declared after the Bootstrap one)

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blog_post_app/base.css' %}">
```

Comment: You can use `font-family: "Courier New" !important;` to override Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to consider is, if you have added {% load static %} at the top of your html page.
Then have a look at your settings and check whether they comply with Django user's guide.